# How to pass optional argument to operator in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to check for approximate equality the prefix form is working

```
≈(0.9, 1; atol = 0.1)
```

Is it possible to specify optional argument in infix form? Something like (the code is not working)

```
0.9 ≈ 1 atol = 0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use prefix function call syntax in order to pass keyword arguments to the function. The `@test` macro provided by the `Test` standard library allows you to supply keyword arguments to `≈` by adding trailing `key=val` pairs like this:

```
julia> using Test

julia> @test 1 ≈ 1.001 rtol=0.001
Test Passed
```

This is a special feature of the `@test` macro, however, not a general feature of operator syntax. There is no way to pass keyword arguments to an operator with infix syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
≈(a, t::Tuple{Float64,Float64}) = isapprox(a, t[1]; atol=t[2])

julia> 1.1 ≈ 1.2
true

julia> 1.0 ≈ (0.9, 0.15)
true
```

Comment: I would not recommend adding methods to `≈` like that. It's a textbook case of type piracy: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy-1.